# I want to redirect http://www.mydomain.com/subfolder/index.php to http://mydomain.com/subforlder/index.php , How can I do this?

Tags: mod-rewrite, .htaccess

I want to redirect http://www.mydomain.com/subfolder/index.php to the **very same url** without the ***WWW prefix***, how can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: I've tried this: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L] , it won't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

of if you prefer this one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The RewriteCond means that if the domain starts with www then it will be redirected to mydomain.com.

Comment: it's not working for me, I have to say, the www.mysite.com is th emirrored version of my site under mydomain.com , any idea what I could try here?`thx

Comment: @user57256 can you post your current virtualhost servername and serveralias configuration and if they are in different virtualhosts, if their documentroot is the same, so i can provide you with a more accurated answer ?